# awk string greater than variable

Tags: awk

Being quite new to Linux and awk, this problem has me stuck. Bet it's easy to get it working. So I have this command that works fine. Printing only lines newer than a minute timestamp as text.

```
awk -F\" '$0> "[01/Nov/2018:15:58" {print $0}' localhost_access_log.2018-11-01.txt
```

The log file is formatted as follows

```
[01/Nov/2018:15:53:16 +0200] x.x.x.10 "-" "-" "libwww-perl/6.13" "GET /manager/status?XML=true HTTP/1.1" 401 2473 1
[01/Nov/2018:15:53:16 +0200] x.x.x.10 "-" "-" "libwww-perl/6.13" "GET /manager/status?XML=true HTTP/1.1" 200 3070 4
[01/Nov/2018:15:58:16 +0200] x.x.x.10 "-" "-" "libwww-perl/6.13" "GET /manager/status?XML=true HTTP/1.1" 401 2473 2
[01/Nov/2018:15:58:16 +0200] x.x.x.10 "-" "-" "libwww-perl/6.13" "GET /manager/status?XML=true HTTP/1.1" 200 3070 4
```

But running the same command from a bash script won't work correctly. This below prints *all* lines from the log file.

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

STAMP=$(date --date '-15 min' "+%d/%b/%Y:%H:")
MIN1=$(date --date '-15 min' "+%M")
MIN1=${MIN1:0:2}
STAMP=$STAMP$MIN1
LOGSTAMP=$(date +%Y-%m-%d)

awk -F\" '$0> "$STAMP" {print $0}' localhost_access_log.$LOGSTAMP.txt
```

And changing "$STAMP" -> $STAMP won't print *anything*.

```
awk -F\" '$0> $STAMP {print $0}' localhost_access_log.$LOGSTAMP.txt
```

Can you help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bash variables don't work in `awk`. You have to pass them into your awk script to an awk variable by using the `-v` flag:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

STAMP=$(date --date '-15 min' "+%d/%b/%Y:%H:")
MIN1=$(date --date '-15 min' "+%M")
MIN1=${MIN1:0:2}
STAMP=$STAMP$MIN1
LOGSTAMP=$(date +%Y-%m-%d)

awk -F\" -v stamp="$STAMP" '$0>stamp {print $0}' localhost_access_log.$LOGSTAMP.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the shell variable into the Awk program string, you need to terminate the single quote string before and restart it after referencing the (quoted) variable.  That gets intricate:

```
awk -F'"' '$0> "'"$STAMP"'" {print $0}' localhost_access_log.$LOGSTAMP.txt
```

What awk sees as the program is then:

```
$0 > "01/Nov/2018:13:15" { print $0 }
```

Comment: That will fail cryptically given some values of $STAMP. Use `-v` and an awk variable instead, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/53104050/1745001. You can delete `{ print $0 }` as that's the default action.